# Which linear transformations are more abundant: dimension-increasing, dimension-preserving or dimension-decreasing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vector-fields

My final aim is to understand the increase of Von Neumann Entropy in quantum systems by analyzing *classes* of unitary matrices in finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. I'm following a potentially very silly path, of equating *scarsity* with *valuable* and *abundant* with *not-valuable*.

For now I have narrowed my quest to a simple question. I want to figure out the cardinality of certain classes of bounded linear transformations $A: V \rightarrow W$ over finite-dimensional vector spaces $V, W$.

My question is:

> Which class of transformations has a higher cardinality, the one with
>   $|V| > |W|$, $|V| < |W|$ or $|V| = |W|$ ?

What I've answered myself so far has been mearly in terms of the *matrices*, not of the operators.

My reasoning so far has been that the class of rectangular matrices with $|V| < |W|$ should have a higher cardinality, simply because its class of equivalnet matrices is bigger since there is more data to play around with: more rows to apply the elementary-row and column operations. Also, as opposed to going "downwards", the  $|V| > |W|$ class,  there is no limit on the size of the codomain.

But I'm realizing now that this doesn't say anything about the *underlying operator*, which is basis independant. I would like to get a basis-independant answer.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this question.

Answer (score 3):

The dimensionality of the Hilbert spaces that a given operator maps to and from (which is the number of rows and columns of any faithful representation) *is* basis independent.  But your question is meaningless unless you define a measure on the space of all linear operators.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Does it make more sense to consider only unitary operators?

Comment: @user130222 Unitary operators must preserve dimension by definition.  Otherwise you can't have both $U^\dagger U = I$ and $U U^\dagger = I$.

Answer (score 3):

Over an infinite field (like ${\mathbb R}$ or ${\mathbb C}$) all finite-dimensional vector spaces have the same cardinality.  When $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, so is $Hom(V,W)$, which therefore also has the same cardinality (independent of $V$ and $W$).

Operators of less than maximal rank have positive codimension (and hence measure zero) in $Hom(V,W)$.  Operators of greater than maximal rank are even rarer.